# how to pass argument in function for this.setattribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

so i am learning javascript(?), and i came across this situation i cannot really find a straight answer for.

so i have these paragraphs in an html page that i want to change the background color for, and the code I have working is this:

```
var colors=['red','pink','blue'];

var div2paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')

for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    (function(paragraph) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function(){
    this.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${colors[paragraph]}`)}
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function(){
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white')}
    })(paragraph);
}
```

I don't quite understand what is going on here either, I was just trying to do this with the whole "function(){}" thing (supposedly called an anonymous function?), but apparently there is something called an IIFE in javascript, so you have to WRAP the function and pass a unique variable to make it run each time within a loop, though i still don't understand why i have to end this with "(paragraph)".

I was thinking whether it is possible to do the same thing by just creating a function for each of these setAttribute actions, so i tried to write it this way:

```
var colors=['red','pink','blue'];

var div2paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')

function changeToColor(color) {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + color);
}

function changeBackWhite() {
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white');
}

for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor('red');
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = changeBackWhite;
}
```

but no matter what i do, it always pretty much comes up with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
```

or something along those lines. i think it has something to do with in these situations, if you add the parenthesis, it calls the function before it does anything else? so it doesn't know what "this" is? i don't quite understand, but in any case I haven't the slightest clue on how to write the same thing i did above with separate functions. would someone be able to shed some light into this...?

I am more used to Python so obviously there are fundamental concepts that are different...

PS: what are the difference between these two examples below?

```
for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = colors[paragraph];
    }
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = 'white';
    }
}
```

and this

```
for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function(){
        this.setAttribute('style', `background-color: $(colors[paragraph]`)
    }
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function(){
        this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white')
    }
}
```

and why does the first one (provided by ibrahim mahrir) work and the second one does not?

Comment: BTW you don't need the inner IIFE inside the loop as you are already using `let`.which respects block scoping.

Comment: More on IIFE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: *So it doesn't know what `this` is?* Yessssss :) [this - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Because your [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is not correct. It should be `\`background-color: ${colors[paragraph]}\`` not `\`background-color: $(colors[paragraph]\``. My solution doesn't use template literals at all, that's why I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: oh thank goodness its just a typo not me going insane. thank you so much sir!

Comment: @user3696118 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code example, the [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/) inside the loop is totally useless as you are already using `let` which respects the block scope, so [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/) won't happen. The following code will work just fine:

```
for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = colors[paragraph];
    };
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = 'white';
    };
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to use `setAttribute` to set the `style` properties. Just do it directly.

**Demo:**

```js
var colors=['red','pink','blue'];

var div2paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p');

for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = colors[paragraph];
    };
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = 'white';
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
    <p>AAAA</p>
    <p>BBBB</p>
    <p>CCCC</p>
</div>
```

---

As for the second code example, your functions need to return other functions to be assigned as event listeners. For example `changeColor` should be defined like so:

```
function changeToColor(color) {
    return function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
}
```

The anonymous function returned by `changeColor` will be assigned to the event listener. In your code `changeColor` returned nothing, so `undefined` is attached to the event listener. Furthermore, `changeColor` is not the event listener itself (it's just a function that creates the event listener and returns it), so `this` inside it will be the global object `window`. `window` don't have a method called `setAttribute`, hence the error.

Also, you don't need `changeBackWhite`, you can use `changeColor` for both (courtesy of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/)), like so:

```
for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor(colors[paragraph]);
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = changeToColor('white');;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var colors=['red','pink','blue'];

var div2paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p');

function changeToColor(color) {
    return function() {
        this.style['background-color'] = color;
    }
}

for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor(colors[paragraph]);
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = changeToColor('white');;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
    <p>AAAA</p>
    <p>BBBB</p>
    <p>CCCC</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm, its interesting how your first example works, the way i originally wrote it was this `for (let paragraph = 0; paragraph < div2paragraphs.length; paragraph++) {
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function(){
        this.setAttribute('style', `background-color: $(colors[paragraph]`)
    }
    div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = function(){
        this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white')
    }
}`

but it still didn't work. does this have something to do with trying to use "setAttribute"?

Comment: @user3696118 No. I bet you used `var` instead of `let`, that's why it didn't work. `var` doen't respect block scope, so the IIFE is needed. But `let` solves that problem, so no need for IIFE.

Comment: no i did use `let`, as exactly as i wrote in the comments, still didn't work

Comment: this was answered in the original post comments,but it was because my "template literal" was not written correctly...

Comment: @user3696118 Yeah, I know. I wrote that original post comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

While assigning on-event handlers, you must assign handler **functions** to the placeholders.

```
div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor('red');
```

The `TypeError` occurs here. The result (returned value) of the invoked `changeToColor` function with the parameter "red" is a variable. This is not a function. Assigned handlers must fit the prototype `function(Event e){...}` where e is an object of the Event class as defined in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

```
div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseout = changeBackWhite;
```

This line however, is correct because you are assigning the ID of a defined *function* to the placeholder, which can then be used as the real handler function.

What you need to do is, rewrite the function changeToColor and assign its ID to the placeholer

```
div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor
```

Or, if you want to immediately invoke the function, you can wrap it within another function that has `this` reference to the context where it's belong to (if the calling function needed `this`), using either `call` or `apply`.

```
div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = function () {
  changeToColor.call(this, 'red');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: hi there, thank you for your response, I actually tried to write it in the last example you typed, and it still gave me the same TypeError....

also with the "div2paragraphs[paragraph].onmouseover = changeToColor" example, how can i pass a custom color to the function?